# Looking to identify this seed

Tags: trees, seeds, weeds

We are located in southern Ontario. I found these seeds in a row (flat sides against each other) in my garden. There is a lot together, so I'm guessing a large pod (its spring so maybe it has degraded and left the seeds behind). They are roundish, and quite flat. I put them on a piece of paper between the lines to see the size. I would say they are 6-7mm.

I am going to clean them up anyway, but want to see if they are worth planting somewhere or if they are invasive and really need to be removed...

Thanks

[image: small brown/red seeds]

Answer (score 1):

I think i found it. Iris pseudacorus (yellow flag iris). I have a few small Iris in my garden but have never seen the seeds, I am guessing something brought the pod near the bird feeder and left me with a puzzle. thanks anyways to those who read the post.

Comment: And its invasive, so I will be getting rid of it...